# Pasar variables entre Hilos C#

Tags: c#, variables, hilos

estoy aprendiendo algo de c#,no puedo pasar variables entre Hilos,me gustaría ver varios métodos para pasar variables entre Hilos,también preguntar,si tengo por ejemplo una variable local dentro de un bucle `for` en la función `static async Task AsyncTask(){}` , como logro acceder a ella desde `Funcion2`

```
 class Program
    {
         static void Main()
        {

Thread hilo = new Thread(Funcion2);
            hilo.Start();

            Task delay = AsyncTask();
            delay.Wait();

            static async Task AsyncTask()
            {      
              int numero = 44;
            }

            static void Funcion2()
            {
               Console.Writeline(numero);
            }          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para compartir data entre hilos es recomendable sincronizar lo hilos para evitar errores. Una de las maneras de hacer esto es usando ManualResetEvent:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netcore-3.1.

En este caso se esta compartiendo una variable de tipo string en los threads,y se esta pasando una variable desde el hilo 1 al hilo2 :

```
class Program
    {
        public static ManualResetEvent SincronizacionHilos = new ManualResetEvent(false);


        static string compartida="";
        
       static Thread thread;

       static Thread thread2;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SincronizacionHilos.Reset();

            Thread thread = new Thread(()=> {
                
                
                hilo1();

                string variableHilo1 = "esta variable es pasada al hilo 2 desde el hilo 1";

                thread2 = new Thread(() => hilo2(variableHilo1));

                thread2.Start();

                SincronizacionHilos.Set();

            });

                thread.Start();


            SincronizacionHilos.Set();



        }

      static void hilo1() {

           

            compartida = "hilo1";

                Console.WriteLine("recurso compartido accedido desde:  "+compartida);

            SincronizacionHilos.WaitOne();


        }

         static void hilo2(string  recibida)
        {
            
                compartida = "hilo2";
            Console.WriteLine("recurso compartido accedido desde: "+compartida);


            Console.WriteLine("variable recibida desde hilo1: " + recibida);


            SincronizacionHilos.WaitOne();
        }


    }
```

Comment: funciona perfectamente,muchas gracias

Comment: Hola! Me pregunto si esto puede funcionar entre hilos de diferentes proyectos de una misma solución. He publicado una pregunta al respecto, en la que intento usar variables entre un Android (Xamarin) y un Xamarin.Forms.